# Monitoring File Read/Write Rates

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nfs, lsof

I have a directory which is NFS-mounted in a virtual machine (kvm), and which is located on the host machine.  I see a lot of net activity between the host & vm, but oddly there is little disk activity visible on the host's disk, where that directory is located.  I've checked `iftop` and all this net activity is indeed between the vm and host.  I know `lsof` allows me to watch what files are open, but I'd like to see read/write rates for files or directories so I can identify more clearly what is happening.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I do only know about **iotop** to monitor read/write to HDD.

`sudo apt-get -y install iotop && sudo iotop`

Comment: Well, that could help, thanks; but I was actually looking to monitor read/write rates for a particular directory so I could see how much that NFS-mounted directory was being hit.  I did solve the problem, though.  It was a networking issue in which, by NFS mounting using the host's local IP, all data was going through the router before going to the host.  I had to use instead the special IP that QEMU offers to connect to the host: [192.168.122.1 (default)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking).